# SWRevealViewController setFrontViewController issue

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cocoa-touch, swrevealviewcontroller

I have a searchbar in my rearviewcontroller. When I click the "search" button, I want my frontView to change (to a searchViewController). The problem is, when i'm pushing with:

```
setFrontViewController:animated:
```

the navigationBar isn't showing anymore. I tried to show it with:

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
```

But it doesn't change anything. I initialize all I need from the navigation bar in the viewDidLoad from the searchViewController. Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: can show the screen shot

Comment: Than you very much but i finally found the solution. I pushed a UINavigationController instead of a ViewController and it works perfectly :)